# How can I force buttons to stay in one line in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button, vuetify.js

I have three buttons in a table and when an other data in the row is too long it expands the table and but the three buttons on top of each other. I want to force my three buttons to stay in one line no matter what.

```
<td class="text-xs-right">
  <div>
    <v-btn class="teal" fab small dark @click.native="$emit('edit', props.item)">
      <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="cyan" fab small @click.native="$emit('remove', props.item)">
      <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="lime" fab small @click.native="$emit('email', props.item)">
      <v-icon>email</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</td>
```

Normal:

[image]

Problem:

[image]

Comment: Assign a minimum width to the column using CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable wrapping on whitespace:

```css
.text-xs-right {
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* To help visualize the fact that the container is too small */
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-xs-right">
  <div>
    <v-btn class="teal" fab small dark @click.native="$emit('edit', props.item)">
      <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="cyan" fab small @click.native="$emit('remove', props.item)">
      <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="lime" fab small @click.native="$emit('email', props.item)">
      <v-icon>email</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, where I set an explicit width, this means the items overflow.

In your table, the column should stretch to fit the content.

Answer (score 1):

Add new class to table wrapper

```
<td class="text-xs-right buttons-cell">
  <div>
    <v-btn class="teal" fab small dark @click.native="$emit('edit', props.item)">
      <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="cyan" fab small @click.native="$emit('remove', props.item)">
      <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn class="lime" fab small @click.native="$emit('email', props.item)">
      <v-icon>email</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</td>
```

Then add css styles with `min-width` property for this class. For example:

```
.buttons-cell {
   min-width: 150px;
}
```